# solucionar error "too many arguments to funtion"

Tags: c++, variables

Tengo un error al cual no entiendo como arreglar, declaro tres variables diferentes con los mismos parámetros pero me dan error.
Este es el error que me da:

[image: este es el error que me da]

Así es como declaro las variables:

```
void escribir();
void mostrar();
void comparar();

int main() {    

char partes[3][15];
escribir(partes);
mostrar(partes;
comparar(partes);
getch();
```

Comment: No puedes enviar valores a funciones que no están definidas para recibirlos.

Answer (score 0):

En el main estás poniendo como parámetros el arreglo bidimensional partes, pero debes también indicar ese parámetro tanto en el prototipo como en la implementación de la función:

```
void escribir(char a[3][15]);  //Puedes poner si quieres a[][15]. Si fuera un
void mostrar(char a[3][15]);   //arreglo unidimensional podrías poner a[]
void comparar(char a[3][15]);  //simplemente.

int main(){
    char partes[3][15];
    escribir(partes);
    mostrar(partes);
    comparar(partes);
    getch();
}
```